# Does RLS Works With PowerBI Embedded

Tags: powerbi

Can RLS be applied on the embedded reports in powerbi?
Can anybody give me some clarity on this if its applied onto the Powerbi embedded then how it is possible?

If this can be applied, please give me details on how to do this. How can the RLS be applied onto the Powerbi Embedded?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a role and username to PowerBI in order to obtain the embedded token. This role will be applied to the embedded report.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should start here. It gives quite thorough description of how RLS can work with Power BI embedded content:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded-row-level-security

Comment: I dont understand how to use this in the embedded scenario??
Are there any examples or video tutorial that explains this?